# Refer to the class object in a class function worked as a callback function in promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a class method which is a callback function in a Promise.

myClass.js:

```
class myClass {

    constructor() {}

    doSomethingAsync(resolve, reject) {        
        let me = this;
        console.log(me); // undefined

        // .... do something that returns either resolve() or reject()

    }

}

export default (new myClass);
```

app.js

```
import ClassA from "myClass.js";

new Promise(ClassA.doSomethingAsync).then(() => {
    // .... do something if success ....
    }
}).catch(() => {
    // ... do something if failed ...
})
```

The problem I have is that `me` inside `doSometingAsync()` is supposed to be referring to `ClassA` but it is shown `undefined`. How can I refer to ClassA inside that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you extract a reference to a function and pass it to something else, it doesn't maintain any knowledge that it is supposed to be a method of some class. It's just a function reference that some other function will call. As a result, it doesn't maintain the binding to the intance's `this`. You can maintain the binding to the instance explicitly using `bind()`

```js
class myClass {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "mark"
  }

  doSomethingAsync(resolve, reject) {
    let me = this;
    console.log(me); 
  }

}

let ClassA = new myClass

new Promise(ClassA.doSomethingAsync.bind(ClassA)).then(() => {
  // .... do something if success ....

}).catch(() => {
  // ... do something if failed ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

use arrow functions :

```
class myClass {

    constructor() {}

    doSomethingAsync = (resolve, reject) => {        
        let me = this;
        console.log(me);     
    }

}

export default (new myClass);
```

Comment: This works, but be aware that this syntax requires a babel plugin: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/

Comment: Unfortunately, Babel isn't available in my project. Chrome reported syntax error using this method.

Comment: @LazNiko then u have to use **ClassA.doSomethingAsync.bind(ClassA)** to achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `this` to the function:

```
constructor() {
  this.doSomethingAsync = this.doSomethingAsync.bind(this);
}
```

Alternative, you can use an arrow function, but I think you need a specific version of babel for this:

```
doSomethingAsync = (resolve, reject) => { ... }
```